# How is it possible for std::optional has_value() to be constexpr?

Tags: c++, c++17

As `std::optional` can change its state at runtime (i.e. an object is attached to it), how is it possible for the `has_value()` method and the `bool operator` to be `constexpr`, therefore evaluated at compile time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

constexpr does not mean it is always evaluated at compile time; it means that if you give a constant value (known at compile time), THEN the result will be const as well.

the constructor is constexpr

```
template < class U = value_type >
constexpr optional( U&& value );
```

thus you may fill an optional so that the compiler already knows at compile time the value is set.

```
std::optional<int> opt(3); // <- optional is valid
```

see
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional/optional